# manager names needed from ids

Tags: mysql, sql

i already was able to fetch the manager ids ,but i would need to be able to fetch the names of those three managers, currently stuck there.

```
select d.manager_id, count(employee_id)
from hr.departments d 
inner join hr.employees e on d.department_id = e.department_id
group by d.manager_id
having count(employee_id) > 5
```

When i try to do

```
select d.manager_id, e.first_name, e.last_name, count(employee_id)
from hr.departments d 
inner join hr.employees e on d.department_id = e.department_id
group by d.manager_id, e.first_name, e.last_name
having count(employee_id) >5
```

i get blank results

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to `join` on `employee_id` as well.

```
select d.manager_id, e1.first_name, e1.last_name, count(e.employee_id)
from hr.departments d 
inner join hr.employees e on d.department_id = e.department_id  
inner join hr.employees e1 on d.manager_id = e1.employee_id
group by d.manager_id, e.first_name, e.last_name
having count(e.employee_id) > 5
```

Comment: That will ignore all department employees except the department manager.

Comment: the question asks for `manager` name, not the `employee name`

Comment: But they still need a count. This query will not count non-manager employees.

Answer (score 0):

```
inner join hr.employees e on d.department_id = e.department_id
group by d.manager_id, e.first_name, e.last_name
```

You need another join to employee to get the manager name.

```
select name.first_name, name.last_name,
...
inner join hr.employees name on d.manager_id = name.employee_id
```

If you wanted to skip the additional join you could,

```
select d.manager_id,
       max(case when d.manager_id = e.employee_id then e.first_name end) first_name,
       max(case when d.manager_id = e.employee_id then e.last_name end) last_name,
       count(*)
from   department d
join   employee e on d.department_id = e.department_id
group by d.manager_id having count(*) > 5
;
```

Answer (score 0):

The problem is with the join.  Have you tried using a subquery.  Something like

```
select d.manager_id, e.first_name, e.last_name, count(employee_id)
from hr.departments d 
     inner join hr.employees e on d.department_id = e.department_id
     INNER JOIN (select d.manager_id, 
                 from hr.departments d 
                    inner join hr.employees e on d.department_id = e.department_id
      group by d.manager_id
       having count(employee_id) > 5) as m on d.manager_id = m.manager_id
group by d.manager_id, e.first_name, e.last_name
```